# How to get model attribute name based on id using Spatie/Activitylog?

Tags: arrays, laravel, model, activitylog

I'm trying to get Employee Name based on employee_id of Task model using attributes properties of Spatie/Activitylog activity_log table.

My model:

```
use LogsActivity;

    protected $fillable = ['id','employee_id', 'name', 'description'......];

    protected static $logAttributes = ['id','employee_id','name', 'description'......];

    protected static $logFillable = true;
    protected static $logUnguarded = true;
```

My controller:

```
    {
        $activity = Activity::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(15);

        return view('adminlte::home', ['activity' => $activity]);
    }
```

My blade:

```
@foreach($activity as $act)

  {{$act->changes['attributes']['employee_id']}}

@endforeach
```

Records saved in properties field:

```
{"attributes":{"id":170,"employee_id":"[\"1\",\"2\"]","name":"test","description":"test",......}}
```

Also, in my blade the result is:

```
|employee_id | name       | description| ...
|------------|------------|------------|--------
|["1","2"]   | test       | test       | ....
```

The question is, how to get Name field based on employee_id. For example in this case, Jon, David(not their IDs(["1","2"]). So, I want to get Names instead of IDs.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would fetch them from the database

1) create a list of ids and fetch them.

```
$employees = Employee::whereIn('id', $activity->pluck('employee_id')->flatten())
    ->get()
    ->mapWithKeys(function ($employee) {
        return [$employee->id => $employee];
    });
```

2) Send it to the front-end

```
return view('adminlte::home', ['activity' => $activity, 'employees' => $employees]);
```

3) Use the mapping to display names

```
@foreach($activity as $act)
     @foreach($act->changes['attributes']['employee_id'] as $employeeId)
          {{ $employees[$employeeId] }}, 
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: ```Invalid argument supplied for foreach()```

Comment: Does the Activity model contain a `$casts` array `$casts = ['employee_id' => 'json'];`

Answer (score 0):

it is in the documentation use : Logging directly related model attributes section.
like this :

```
return LogOptions::defaults()
    ->logOnly(['name', 'text', **'user.name'**]);
```

in your case employee.name.